# Is there a cleaner way to write this SCSS code?

Tags: css, django, sass

I'm building a Saleor Site and I'm relatively new to Django and SASS.

I'm currently making my own styling rules in my SCSS files where there's some duplicated code and I feel like there's probably a way of reducing the amount of that duplicated code. Couldn't find any style guides in regards to SCSS.

Can I get some suggestions on a better way of doing this code?

```
.p {
    &-around {
        &_none {
            padding: $none;
        }
        &_x-small {
            padding: $x-small;
        }
        &_small {
            padding: $small;
        }
        &_medium {
            padding: $medium;
        }
        &_large {
            padding: $large;
        }
        &_x-large {
            padding: $x-large;
        }
    }
    &-top {
        /* only real difference is just "padding-top" instead of "padding" */
        &_none { 
            padding-top: $none;
        }
        &_x-small {
            padding-top: $x-small;
        }
        &_small {
            padding-top: $small;
        }
        &_medium {
            padding-top: $medium;
        }
        &_large {
            padding-top: $large;
        }
        &_x-large {
            padding-top: $x-large;
        }
    }
    /* There's more with right, bottom, vertical, horizontal padding as well */
}
```

All input is welcome.

Edit:
This is the resulting code, thank you so much Jakob for making this much cleaner.

```
@each $size, $value in (
    'none'   : $none,
    'x-small': $x-small,
    'small'  : $small,
    'medium' : $medium,
    'large'  : $large,   
    'x-large': $x-large        
){
    .p {
        &-around_#{$size}     { padding:        $value; }
        &-vertical_#{$size}   { padding-top:    $value; padding-bottom: $value; }
        &-horizontal_#{$size} { padding-left:   $value; padding-right:  $value; }
        &-top_#{$size}        { padding-top:    $value; }
        &-bottom_#{$size}     { padding-bottom: $value; }
        &-right_#{$size}      { padding-right:  $value; }
        &-left_#{$size}       { padding-left:   $value; }
    }
    .m {
        &-around_#{$size}     { margin:        $value; }
        &-vertical_#{$size}   { margin-top:    $value; margin-bottom: $value; }
        &-horizontal_#{$size} { margin-left:   $value; margin-right:  $value; }
        &-top_#{$size}        { margin-top:    $value; }
        &-bottom_#{$size}     { margin-bottom: $value; }
        &-right_#{$size}      { margin-right:  $value; }
        &-left_#{$size}       { margin-left:   $value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would use `map`, `@each` loop and interpolation `#{}`- like:

```
$padding: (
    'none'   : none,
    'x-small': 1px,
    'small'  : 2px,
    'medium' : 3px,
    'large'  : 4px,   
    'x-large': 5px        
);

.p {
    @each $size, $value in $padding {
        &-around_#{$size} { padding:        $value; }  
        &-top_#{$size}    { padding-top:    $value; }       
        &-right_#{$size}  { padding-right:  $value; }       
        &-bottom_#{$size} { padding-bottom: $value; }               
        &-left_#{$size}   { padding-left:   $value; }               
    }
}
```

If you like to keep the variables you can do:

```
.p {
    @each $size, $value in (
        'none'   : $none,
        'x-small': $x-small,
        'small'  : $small,
        'medium' : $medium,
        'large'  : $large,   
        'x-large': $x-large        
    ){
        &-around_#{$size} { padding:        $value; }  
        &-top_#{$size}    { padding-top:    $value; }       
        &-right_#{$size}  { padding-right:  $value; }       
        &-bottom_#{$size} { padding-bottom: $value; }               
        &-left_#{$size}   { padding-left:   $value; }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be the best way to do it.

```
.p {
    &-around, &-top {
        &_none {
            padding: $none;
        }
        &_x-small {
            padding: $x-small;
        }
        &_small {
            padding: $small;
        }
        &_medium {
            padding: $medium;
        }
        &_large {
            padding: $large;
        }
        &_x-large {
            padding: $x-large;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I like that. Then I can condense the padding tops to the classes that are affected by padding-top. Thanks!

Comment: This does not produce the same output